# laravel eloquent lazy load model attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to lazy load model attributes.

The use case is that I have a query with a select statement and it might be the case that the returned model misses an attribute that is later required.

I know that adding the attribute to the select statement would be the easy solution, but it could be that someone forgets to do this.

Is there some way to enforce that it is loaded when used? Otherwise it will be treated as if the value is null, which is not what I want here.

My ideal scenario is like with the relationship lazy loading:

If I have not loaded/selected the column it will trigger a separate DB query.
I can enable a strict mode that will throw an exception during development if this happens so I am then aware that I need to add it to the select statement.

Comment: "it could be that someone forgets to do this" That should be pretty obvious when the data they're trying to use is all nulls.

Comment: My experience dictates that if "it ould be that someone forgets to do this" then that person needs training, the code base needs better (or have if not) tests, and the last solution is to create a class (like a repository or domain) that already gives you the data back that you need/want, so no one FORGETS anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to set `preventAccessingMissingAttributes` in the `AppServiceProvider.php` like so:

```php
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Model::preventAccessingMissingAttributes(!$this->app->isProduction());
    }
```

This will prevent laravel from just returning `null` if you try to access a non-existing attribute.
Instead it would throw `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MissingAttributeException`.

In this way you can easily find such problems during development and avoid situation wher you mistakenly think that an attribute is `null`.